# Save Latex in formats different from pdf for publishing

Tags: conversion, convert

I've made a math book with Latex and I got the pdf. I would like to convert it to epub, or doc, or html without losing much of its quality. Any tips? Is there any other format other than pdf on which Latex works fine?

Comment: You're probably looking for TeX4HT https://tug.org/tex4ht/ which can get you to HTML among other formats.

Comment: Do not use LaTeX as source to export to several formats, Work in the simplest format (i.e., markdown)  and export to LaTeX or whatever.  This way work well almost always, bu the apposite almost never because before or after, you will be tempted to use something in your source that is not exportable.